# Ruby on Rails action on all objects in an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have a list of emails in an array, let's say ~2000 emails.

```
emails = ["AllenXiang@boyaa.com", "2dlogic@gmail.com", "support@KalromSystems.com", "kangisupport@helendorongroup.com", "James@APPCRASHCOURSE.COM", "James@appcrashcourse.com", "SpartanAppsUK@gmail.com"]
```

Let's say I theoretically want to get the emails site name. So I want to do `emails.each do |email| puts email.split("@")[1]`

Which would get me each of the site names for the emails. But I'm curious, is there a faster way to get that out of the array?

Ideally I'd like to create an `array.uniq` that contains a unique list of every site linked to the emails. I could do this manually, but I'm wondering if there's a quicker way to do this on the array itself (the array I actually have is ~2 million emails in length).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're creating isn't really an array, which cares about order and doesn't care about uniqueness. You want a [Set](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html), which doesn't concern itself with order, but doesn't allow duplicates.

```
require 'set'

email_domains = Set.new
emails.each do |email|
  email_domains.add email.split('@', 2).last
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this solution

```
emails.map { |email| email.split('@').last }.uniq
```

**Updated**

Or this one

```
emails.collect { |email| email.split('@').last }.uniq
```